# EFCore scaffold

Tags: entity-framework, scaffold

I am trying to create a Model, by using scaffold:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "DataSource=database.sqlite" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -o Model
```

But this return error:

```
Could not scaffold the foreign key 'PoolsInDepartments(pools_id)'. A key for 'id' was not found in the principal entity type 'Pools'.
Could not scaffold the foreign key 'PoolsInDepartments(departaments_id)'. A key for 'id' was not found in the principal entity type 'Departments'.
```

I don't understund where error in my PoolInDepertaments table. Please, check my database:
https://pastebin.com/Mmi6fnrV

And diagram for this DB:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV7EB.png

Comment: I uploading sqlite3 file
https://www.sendspace.com/file/hwixx7

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command:

Scaffold-DbContext "Filename=mydatabase.sqlite3" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -OutputDir Models

I use this since the first versions of EF Core until the new 2.1 and it works for me.